# Auto send a form as action from php file

Tags: php, post, action

I am trying to send a form to 2 different processors.  One is a 3rd party cloud database that I do not control nor have the code for.  The other my simple contact form processor.  I was trying something like:

```
<form action="mail.php" method="POST">
<input name="name" type="text" />
<input type='submit' name='submit' onclick="this.form.action="//3rdpartcloud.com";" />
```

From what I understand this wont work because it leaves the page on the 1st action and cant do the 2nd action.

I have seen Ajax suggestions, but no clear example.  But as I will be sending the same variables to both files, I was thinking it would be easier to POST all variables to my php form, and then from my php to automatically POST them to the 3rd party server.  I do not know how they process the data so I want to send it as form values not as variables.

Is there a simpler way to achieve this?  What is the correct syntax?  I'm guessing something like this in the php:

```
<form action="site.com" method="POST">
<input name="name" value=$name>
```

But even if that works - how do I auto send it to an action url?

Comment: Ajax is the way to go. Clear example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960240/jquery-ajax-submit-form

Comment: Again no clear code on how to send to 2 actions, and would need the browser using javascript.

Comment: Consecutively. First, then second. Yes, browser will need to use javascript.

Comment: The link also uses Jquery, I would prefer not to use it.  If it is done in php no client side frameworks needed

Comment: Then use curl http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php to submit form data from your server.

Answer (score 1):

First sumit your form using ajax to your own site - then submit the form to the other site as usual.

Your Ajax - something look something like this:

```
<form id="form" action="theothersite.php" method="POST">
    <input name="name" type="text" />
    <input type='submit' id="submitbutton" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" >

$('#submitbutton').click(function(e){

   e.preventDefault();  //stops form submission

   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url : '/yoursiteurl.php',
       data: $('#form').serialize(),
       success: function(data){
           $('#form').submit(); //now submit the form
       }
    });

})

</script>
```

In your PHP do a:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

To see the submitted values

Comment: How does this pass the data to the php file?  print_r($_POST['formdata']); shows nothing. (also needs to add a ').  The form is already to process the data as is.  And the question was how to do it through php?

Comment: I've updated my answer - the post vars should match whats posted by the form - I've just ditched the 'formdata' var and serialized the form directly into the ajax data.  You should be able to preview all posted data with print_r($_POST)